# How convert pq.Int64Array to string?

Tags: postgresql, go

In `Golang` application I make sql query to **PostgreSQL** database which return me array of int.

```
var identifiers [] pq.Int64Array

// Execute SQL query by "database/sql" package.
if err := database.DBSQL.QueryRow(sqlStatement.String()).Scan(&identifiers); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    utils.ResponseWithError(responseWriter, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
    return
}
```

How convert `identifiers` array with `pq.Int64Array` elements to string where elements of array separated by comma?

Answer (score 0):

Because the type `pq.Int64Array` is a slice type, the application is scanning to a slice of slices. Scan to a slice only:

```
var identifiers pq.Int64Array
if err := database.DBSQL.QueryRow(sqlStatement.String()).Scan(&identifiers); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    utils.ResponseWithError(responseWriter, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
    return
}
```

Convert each id to a string and append to a buffer.  Insert separators between each id.  Convert the buffer to a string when done.

```
var buf []byte
for i, id := range identifiers {
    if i > 0 {
        buf = append(buf, ',')
    }
    buf = strconv.AppendInt(buf, int64(id), 10)
}
s := string(buf)
```

Comment: Hello! I tested your code right now. It raise such error: `Cannot convert expression on type pq.Int64Array to type int64`. Do you have any ideas?